# What's the fundamental principle regarding who should hold which key (public vs. private)?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key-encryption

In a SSH logging scenario, the client keeps the private key while the server stores the public key under its ./ssh directory.

In a different scenario, such as SSL, it's the server that keeps the private key and give away its corresponding public keys to the end users.

I read a lot about the two keys online, they are either off the topic or too deep for a beginner. Could someone explain using plain language about what is the governing rule here determining who should hold what key? Thanks very much.

Comment: The private key is always kept by the party that generated the key pair. Public keys are handed out to everyone (the public) who might want to send something to the person with the private key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all cases, the party **which is being authenticated** holds the private key (actually both keys, the whole set). The party which is verifying authentication only needs to know the public key.

Both SSH and TLS/SSL actually support authenticating **both** the client and the server, so each connection may use two different keypairs – one to verify the server's identity (server holds the private key) and one to verify the client's identity (client holds the private key).

For example, in SSH, the server's `authorized_keys` file holds client public keys, but the client's `known_hosts` file holds server public keys.

When you're being asked to verify the "hostkey fingerprint" when making an SSH connection, you're seeing the server's public key, and the server stores its private key in /etc/ssh. Once that step is done, the client presents its own public key to the server.

(The same thing exists in TLS as "client certificate authentication", but it is somewhat rare in comparison – but even though it's very rare on the web, many browsers support it anyway.)

Comment: I can't believe my luck! Such a condensed and yet valuable answer! It beats the whole class that I have paid on Udamy:)

Comment: By the way, dear grawity, I'd seriously like to pay you to be my remote mentor, is it possible? How can I reach you? Thank you.

Comment: Just one clarification, when you mention `Once that step is done, the client presents its own public key to the server.` you meant uploading your own public key to the server's `\ssh` direction, it's not necessary every time you login, is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, I meant the client software automatically sending the key as part of the SSH connection establishment, so that the server could _compare it against_ what was previously manually uploaded to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: Then did you mean it would actually `send` the key, or use that key to encrypt a message and send that message to test if the other end can decrypt?

Comment: In SSHv2: first the client _sends_ the public key to check whether it's acceptable; then, if it's acceptable, the server sends it a random challenge and the client replies back with a _signature_ proving that it owns the private key as well.

Comment: You mention testing for decryption – that's another possible approach, and it was used in e.g. SSHv1, but it has the downside that not all public-key algorithms actually _support_ encryption/decryption at all. For example, ECDSA and Ed25519 are signing-only. So in both SSHv2 and TLS, the signature method is used instead.